# How do I import a database created in phpMyAdmin, then exported, then modified in Bluefish, back into phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, importerror, bluefish

I created a database in phpMyAdmin, then exported it to the desktop. I opened the sql in Bluefish and added 50 new rows (because it was much quicker than adding them individually in phpMyAdmin). When I try to import the same (but modified) file back into phpMyAdmin, phpMyAdmin accepts all of the rows that were exported but freaks out and rejects all of the new rows that I entered using Bluefish. I end up with the same file as I originally exported.

I've tried deleting the original table and importing the modified one using the same name and with a totally different name but the results are the same. All new entries are rejected with error message "Unexpected beginning of statement."